Merge and subtract annotations in COCO segmentation json format
I'm new to Python and machine learning and I have the following problem: I have annotated data in the COCO .json format. In this case, it is the surface area of corals on underwater photos that are alive and parts of corals that are dead. Sometimes, the masks overlap.
I want to subtract the area I annotated as "dead" from the areas I annotated as "alive". On each photo, only one coral is annotated, sometimes I did this in multiple parts, therefore I also want to merge the masks of each class before the subtraction. The annotation class "dead" only occurs in a subset of the images.
Could somebody point me in the right direction on how to do this?
I added an example photo: In yellow is the class "alive", in green the class "dead".

Thanks a lot!

My ultimate aim is to have the area (in pixels) and the RGB values of each pixel in annotations of the class "alive" that do not additionally belong to the class "dead". Maybe, this can be achieved without merging and subtracting masks.

I managed to find a solution with the help of GitHub copilot. If anybody is interested, here is a code that

Loops through all images in a coco data set
Select pixels that belong to Category 1 but not to Category 2 or 3 (if Categories 2 and 3 exist for the image)
Plots the filtered annotation layer
And returns a list with the pixel coordinates, RGB values, and filename

The category_ids are taken from the name of the category (input to function).
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_rgb_values(coco, img_folder, cat1_name, cat2_name, cat3_name):
    # Initialize list to store data
    data = []

# Get all categories
categories = coco.loadCats(coco.getCatIds())

# Get category IDs for the given names
cat1_id = next((cat['id'] for cat in categories if cat['name'] == cat1_name), None)
cat2_id = next((cat['id'] for cat in categories if cat['name'] == cat2_name), None)
cat3_id = next((cat['id'] for cat in categories if cat['name'] == cat3_name), None)

if cat1_id is None or cat2_id is None or cat3_id is None:
    raise ValueError('Category not found')

# Get all images
img_ids = coco.getImgIds()

for img_id in img_ids:
    # Get image info
    img_info = coco.loadImgs(img_id)[0]
    filename = img_info['file_name']

    # Load image
    img = np.array(Image.open(img_folder + '/' + filename))

    # Get annotations of category 1
    ann_ids_cat1 = coco.getAnnIds(imgIds=img_id, catIds=cat1_id)
    anns_cat1 = coco.loadAnns(ann_ids_cat1)

    # Get mask for category 1
    mask_cat1 = np.zeros((img_info['height'], img_info['width']))
    for ann in anns_cat1:
        mask_cat1 = np.logical_or(mask_cat1, coco.annToMask(ann))

    # Get annotations of category 2
    ann_ids_cat2 = coco.getAnnIds(imgIds=img_id, catIds=cat2_id)
    anns_cat2 = coco.loadAnns(ann_ids_cat2)

    # Get annotations of category 3
    ann_ids_cat3 = coco.getAnnIds(imgIds=img_id, catIds=cat3_id)
    anns_cat3 = coco.loadAnns(ann_ids_cat3)

    # If category 2 or 3 exists, modify the mask for category 1
    if anns_cat2 or anns_cat3:
        # Get mask for category 2
        mask_cat2 = np.zeros((img_info['height'], img_info['width']))
        for ann in anns_cat2:
            mask_cat2 = np.logical_or(mask_cat2, coco.annToMask(ann))

        # Get mask for category 3
        mask_cat3 = np.zeros((img_info['height'], img_info['width']))
        for ann in anns_cat3:
            mask_cat3 = np.logical_or(mask_cat3, coco.annToMask(ann))

        # Modify mask for pixels in category 1 and not in category 2 or 3
        mask_cat1 = np.logical_and(mask_cat1, np.logical_not(mask_cat2))
        mask_cat1 = np.logical_and(mask_cat1, np.logical_not(mask_cat3))

    # Get RGB values and positions
    positions = np.argwhere(mask_cat1)
    red = img[:,:,0][mask_cat1]
    green = img[:,:,1][mask_cat1]
    blue = img[:,:,2][mask_cat1]

    # Add to data list
    for (y, x), r, g, b in zip(positions, red, green, blue):
        data.append({'filename': filename, 'Red': r, 'Green': g, 'Blue': b, 'X': x, 'Y': y})

    # Display the image with the mask overlay
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.imshow(mask_cat1, alpha=0.5, cmap='jet')
    plt.show()

# Create DataFrame from list of dictionaries
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

return df

